# Jenkins - Create a job which triggers a various number of parallels scripts

Tags: shell, jenkins, jobs

We have a Jenkins job which has a directory as parameter. Depending on the number of files in the directory, it executes a shell script several times.

We want these script executions to be parallels instead of sequentials. How can we do it?

Example: if there is 6 files in the directory, the script should be executed 5 times. If there is 15 files, the script should be executed 10 times.

Comment: I don't get the logic behind _6 files => 5 runs_ and _15 files => 10 runs_. But you can still implement that in Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parallel` step of Jenkins Pipeline plugin (formerly known as Workflow plugin) to execute tasks in parallel. Please refer to the [tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) and this [blog article on jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/06/16/parallel-test-executor-plugin/) for more information. Hope this helps!

Comment: I can second this. I have an example, which does something _very_ similar [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/7463d28cd2a9c07c1c5192e4421d55e8b56531b4/src/org/typo3/chefci/v1/TestKitchen.groovy#L28-L58). The only difference I would say is that the information about what is parallelized comes from calling the command `kitchen list` instead of listing files.